# Populate stock predictions in django database with models

Tags: python, django, database

I have a code which outputs the prediction of stocks. I've been trying to figure out how to populate the predictions into the database. Every time the code runs, it should modify the database with the new predictions.

This is my 'predictions.py':

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np # Processing data as arrays
import pandas as pd # Used to create a dataframe that holds all data
from keras.models import load_model # Used to load existing models
import datetime
import joblib
from Dashboards.models import Predictions


def models_loader(folder, name, days = [1, 5, 30]):
    model = []
    for i in days:
        model.append(load_model(folder+'/'+ name + '_' + str(i) + '.h5'))
    return model

days = [1,5,14,30,90] #Day intervals
scaler = joblib.load('scaler.sav')

models = models_loader('ML Model','Model', days) #Load models 

has_Run = False
companies = ['TSLA', 'AAPL','SIRI','GGB','PLUG']

while True:
    print("Has started")
    time = datetime.datetime.today()
    schedule = datetime.time(17,0,0)
    if time.hour == schedule.hour and has_Run==False: #change second time hour to schedule hour
        last = datetime.date.today() 
        td = datetime.timedelta(100)
        start = last - td
    
        for symbols in companies:
            print(symbols)
            predINV= []
            data = yf.download(symbols,start = start, end = last)
            data = data.filter(['Close'])
            if len(data.index) > 59:
                INPUT = data.values
                INPUT = INPUT[-60:]
                scaled_input = scaler.fit_transform(INPUT)
                scaled_input = np.reshape(scaled_input, (-1,60,1))
                for i in range(len(days)):
                    pred = models[i].predict(scaled_input) 
                    predINV.append(scaler.inverse_transform(pred))
                    predINV[i] = predINV[i].round(decimals = 2)
                    print(f'Day {days[i]}: {predINV[i]}')

                    pred_to_db = Predictions(symbol=symbols, day1=predINV[0], day5=predINV[1], day14=predINV[2], day30=predINV[3], day90=predINV[4])
                    pred_to_db.save()

                    stocks = Predictions.objects.all()

                    for stock in stocks:
                    
                        stock.symbol = symbols
                        stock.day1 = predINV[0]
                        stock.day5 = predINV[1]
                        stock.day14 = predINV[2]
                        stock.day30 = predINV[3]
                        stock.day90 = predINV[4]

                    stock.save(update_fields=['symbol', 'day1', 'day5', 'day14', 'day30', 'day90'])
        
            del data 
            has_Run = True  

      elif has_Run==True and time.hour != schedule.hour:
         has_Run=False
```

(This is what I want to populate to DB. It should populate all the data and every time the code runs modify the rows with the new values.)
Output of 'predictions.py' looks like this:

```
Has started
TSLA
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Day 1: [[836.88]]
Day 5: [[836.88]]
Day 14: [[836.07]]
Day 30: [[835.21]]
Day 90: [[827.17]]
AAPL
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Day 1: [[163.32]]
Day 5: [[163.32]]
Day 14: [[163.69]]
Day 30: [[163.57]]
Day 90: [[163.04]]
SIRI
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Day 1: [[6.17]]
Day 5: [[6.17]]
Day 14: [[6.16]]
Day 30: [[6.15]]
Day 90: [[6.12]]
....
```

This is my 'models.py':

```
class Predictions(models.Model):
  '''Predictions Table to maintain stock predictions'''
  symbol = models.CharField(default='', max_length=1)
  day1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
  day5 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
  day14 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
  day30 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
  day90 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem better? If you're asking about how to set up the server to fill your data, then Django docs are your friend. If you just want a simple script to persist your data in the DB, I think creating a Django server might not be the answer.

Comment: Thank you for responding. My problem is in creating the script to load the data into the DB. I have a web app using the Django framework for stock analysis and I want to be able to pull that data from the DB and display it in the web app but I can't figure out how to insert it in the DB.

Comment: Are you running your script from the Django server, or is it standalone? Also, is the script going to be deployed on the same machine as the Web app?

Comment: The script is standalone, it will be scheduled to run everyday at a certain time to update the DB. And yes, the script is going to be deployed on the same machine as the Web app.

Comment: I suggest creating a Django management command. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/ for more info. You run it every day by calling `python manage.py <your_command_name>` from the project folder. Inside of the command you can access all models and run CRUD operations on them.